как сделать отдельный xml файл для разметки
мне нужно создать файл в котором будут все параметры, т.е. если я менял их там, они бы менялись во всем проекте
Пример: Условно есть 10 TextView с такими параметрами:
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="17sp"
       android:maxEms="7"
       android:breakStrategy="balanced"
       android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
       android:textColor="@color/black" />

Можно ли хотя бы какие то параметры вызывать из файла xml, например все что связанно со шрифтом(размер, семейство, цвет)?

Все нужные свойства объектов нужно хранить в каком то файле (SharedPreferences, БД, JSON, TXT - и тд и тп), а дальше программно выставлять нужные значения.

Это называется стиль. Создается отдельно и подставляется через одноименный атрибут. Параметры шрифта можно добавлять отдельно через font-family
